# clean html white space and new lines

Tags: php, html

How can i clean my html output of double whitespaces and new lines
but not modifing the ones in textarea and pre tags using php?

Comment: In what context? On a server? Where does the HTML come from? Please clarify

Comment: Sample input and sample output would probably be helpful. Also, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would rather say : **don't do this** :

- There is a risk that you'll introduce errors
- This is not needed : your *cleaned* HTML will be rendered the same as the original one
- You will not gain much on the page's size -- there are many other optimizations that should be done before trying to minify HTML.

Still, if you really want to do that, you are probably looking for an **HTML Minifier**.

There are several tools that exist, to do that ; here are a couple of exemples :

- In PHP : https://code.google.com/p/minify/source/browse/trunk/min/lib/Minify/HTML.php
- In PHP : you might want to take a look at the source-code of [smarty's `{strip}` tag](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.strip.tpl)
- In JAVA : https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/
- In JavaScript : https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier

Comment: thanks. well i am curious how much of improvement it will have